# DMARC Report: Why would SPF 'fail' at the policy level but then 'pass' at the auth_results level?

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

Within a DMARC report, why would there be a `<spf>fail</spf>` at the `<policy_evaluated>` level and in the same record have a `<auth_results>` deliver a `<spf>` result of `<result>pass</result>`? Is there some additional analysis after the policy is evaluated (which results in a fail) that ends up approving the email spf? I am trying to understand the steps utilized to approve/reject an email. Thank you for any input you can provide.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64411569

Comment: @glts ... My searches did not find this specific reference so THANK YOU! I believe this does provide the resources I need to satisfy the question. Again, much appreciated.